# What is wrong with my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

My query (below) doesn't work.  I kinda know WHY it doesn't work, but I need help fixing it.  Basically I'm trying to do the following:

Get all rows from FireEvent
Get all rows from HitEvent which are within -5/5 seconds of a FireEvent, if a HitEvent has already been "paired" which a FireEvent then I do not want to include it again.  Basically, I do not want any HitEvent to appear in my query more than once!  I was told in the SQL chat room to play around with RANK, it seems as though it would work if I could figure out how to include the EventTime from FireEvent in my subquery...

Anyway, here is the query...

```
SELECT FireEvent.ExerciseID, 
       FireEvent.FireEventID, 
       tempHitEvent.HitEventID, 
       FireEvent.AssociatedPlayerID, 
       tempHitEvent.AssociatedPlayerID, 
       FireEvent.EventTime, 
       tempHitEvent.EventTime, 
       FireEvent.Longitude, 
       FireEvent.Latitude, 
       tempHitEvent.Longitude, 
       tempHitEvent.Latitude, 
       tempHitEvent.HitResult, 
       FireEvent.AmmunitionCode, 
       FireEvent.AmmunitionSource, 
       FireEvent.FireEventID, 
       0 AS 'IsArtillery' 
FROM   FireEvent 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT HitEvent.*, 
                         FireEvent.FireEventID, 
                         Rank() 
                           OVER ( 
                             ORDER BY HitEvent.EventTime) AS RankValue 
                  FROM   HitEvent 
                         INNER JOIN FireEvent 
                                 ON FireEvent.EventTime BETWEEN 
                                    Dateadd(millisecond, -5000, 
                                    HitEvent.EventTime) AND 
                                               Dateadd(millisecond, 
                                               5000, HitEvent.EventTime) AND HitEvent.FiringPlayerID = FireEvent.PlayerID 
                   AND HitEvent.AmmunitionCode = 
                       FireEvent.AmmunitionCode
                   AND HitEvent.ExerciseID = 
                       'D289D508-1479-4C17-988C-5F6A847AE51E' 
                        AND FireEvent.ExerciseID = 
                       'D289D508-1479-4C17-988C-5F6A847AE51E' 
                   AND HitEvent.HitResult NOT IN ( 0, 1 ) ) AS 
                 tempHitEvent 
              ON ( 
              RankValue = 1
            AND tempHitEvent.FireEventID = 
                     FireEvent.FireEventID 
                     )
WHERE  FireEvent.ExerciseID = 'D289D508-1479-4C17-988C-5F6A847AE51E' 
ORDER BY HitEventID
```

Comment: What error are u getting when u execute the query ?

Comment: It's not an error which I get from SQL.  It's that I'm not getting back the correct records.  The subquery (LEFT JOIN (SELECT HitEvent.*) doesn't work as it doesn't have access to FireEvent (from the outer query) at that time.  That's what I need, or I need another approach to get the records as described in the question...

Comment: Do you care about optimizing the pairing?  For example, if two FireEvents occur at times T+1 and T+5 and there are HitEvents at times T+4 and T+7, you may get one or two pairs.  If FE T+5 pairs with HE T+4, being closest, that leaves FE T+1 out in the cold.  Otheriwse you could get (FE T+1, HE T+4) and (FE T+5, HE T+7).

Comment: @user92546 Ideally I'd like to leave as little out in the cold as possible. I originally did this with cursors but it was fairly slow. So if the ONLY way to do it with joins is to leave some stuff out I'm fine with that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is that you're using `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`. If any hitevent differs from matched fireevents by the same amount, then they will both have a rank of 1, meaning you will get duplicates. As per our conversation in chat, wrap the whole query in a subquery, get rid of the inner subquery now and do a straight join, then just limit to `HitRank = 1` from the outer query and you'll be golden.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will satisfy your stated requirements, assuming I haven't introduced a bug. I can't test the code, but I believe I have the concepts correct. There could easily be a typo or some other silly bug that you will have to track down. But I am confident that you only need a single join in a CTE, and you can select your final results directly from the CTE.

You are not very specific as to how you want to match a hit event with a fire event. You never want a hit event to appear twice, so I partition by HitEventID. I'm assuming you want to pair them in a way that minimizes the difference between the two event times. So I order by the absolute value of the difference between the two events, and I break any tie by the FireEventID.

*EDIT - moved HitResult filter from where clause to outer join clause.

EDIT2 - appended to final where clause to preserve all unmatched FireEvents (HitEventID is null)*

```
with RankedHits as (
  select F.ExcerciseID,
         F.FireEventID,
         H.HitEventID,
         F.AssociatedPlayerID as FireAssociatedPlayerID,
         H.AssociatedPlayerID as HitAssociatedPlayerID,
         F.EventTime as FireEventTime,
         H.EventTime as HitEventTime,
         F.Longitude as FireLongitude,
         F.Latitude as FireLatitude,
         H.Longitude as HitLongitude,
         H.Latitude as HitLatitude,
         H.HitResult,
         F.AmmunitionCode,
         F.AmmunitionSource,
         F.FireEventID,
         rank() over( partition by HitEventID
                      order by abs( datediff( ms, H.EventTime, F.EventTime ) ),
                               F.FireEventID
                    ) as HitRank
    from FireEvent F
    left join HitEvent H
      on F.AmmunitionCode = H.AmmunitionCode
     and F.PlayerID = H.FiringPlayerID
     and F.ExcerciseID = H.ExcerciseID
     and H.HitResult not in( 0, 1 )
     and F.EventTime between dateadd(millisecond, -5000, H.EventTime)
                         and dateadd(millisecond,  5000, H.EventTime)
   where F.ExcerciseID = 'D289D508-1479-4C17-988C-5F6A847AE51E'
)
select ExcerciseID,
       FireEventID,
       HitEventID,
       FireAssociatedPlayerID,
       HitAssociatedPlayerID,
       FireEventTime,
       HitEventTime,
       FireLongitude,
       FireLatitude,
       HitLongitude,
       HitLatitude,
       HitResult,
       AmmunitionCode,
       AmmunitionSource,
       FireEventID,
       0 as IsArtillery
  from RankedHits
 where HitRank=1 or HitEventID is null
```

*EDIT in response to comment*

Here is fixed code derived from your comment link. The critical error was the HitRank=1 filter was missing from the end. Also substituted HitResult for HitRank in the select list.

Not necessary, but I also compared player excercise IDs to the fire event excercise ID instead of a string literal. That makes it easier to change the excercise ID in the future since the string literal now only appears once in the query.

I prefer CTE syntax, but I kept the inline view syntax in the FROM clause as you seem to prefer.

*EDIT2 - appended to final where clause to preserve all unmatched FireEvents (HitEventID is null)*

```
INSERT #Events (
        exerciseid,
        fireeventid,
        hiteventid,
        firingplayerid,
        hitplayerid,
        firingplayerunitid,
        hitplayerunitid,
        firingplayerassociatedplayerid,
        hitplayerassociatedplayerid,
        firingtime,
        hittime,
        firinglongitude,
        firinglatitude,
        hitlongitude,
        hitlatitude,
        hitresult,
        ammunitioncode,
        ammunitionsource,
        eventid,
        isartillery
)
(
  SELECT ExerciseID, FireEventID, HitEventID, FiringPlayerID, HitPlayerID,
         FiringUnitID, HitUnitID, FireAssociatedPlayerID, HitAssociatedPlayerID,
         FireEventTime, HitEventTime, FireLongitude, FireLatitude, HitLongitude,
         HitLatitude, HitRank, AmmunitionCode, AmmunitionSource, EventID, 0
  FROM (
  select FireEvent.ExerciseID,
         FireEvent.FireEventID,
         HitEvent.HitEventID,
         FireEvent.PlayerID as FiringPlayerID,
         HitEvent.PlayerID as HitPlayerID,
         FiringPlayer.UnitID as FiringUnitID,
         HitPlayer.UnitID as HitUnitID,
         FireEvent.AssociatedPlayerID as FireAssociatedPlayerID,
         HitEvent.AssociatedPlayerID as HitAssociatedPlayerID,
         FireEvent.EventTime as FireEventTime,
         HitEvent.EventTime as HitEventTime,
         FireEvent.Longitude as FireLongitude,
         FireEvent.Latitude as FireLatitude,
         HitEvent.Longitude as HitLongitude,
         HitEvent.Latitude as HitLatitude,
         HitEvent.HitResult,
         FireEvent.AmmunitionCode,
         FireEvent.AmmunitionSource,
         FireEvent.FireEventID AS 'EventID',
         rank() over( partition by HitEventID
                      order by abs( datediff( ms, HitEvent.EventTime, FireEvent.EventTime ) ),
                               FireEvent.FireEventID
                    ) as HitRank
    from FireEvent
    left join HitEvent
      on FireEvent.ExerciseID = HitEvent.ExerciseID
      and FireEvent.AmmunitionCode = HitEvent.AmmunitionCode
     and FireEvent.PlayerID = HitEvent.FiringPlayerID
     and HitEvent.HitResult not in( 0, 1 )
     and FireEvent.EventTime between dateadd(millisecond, -5000, HitEvent.EventTime)
                         and dateadd(millisecond,  5000, HitEvent.EventTime)
    LEFT JOIN Player FiringPlayer
           ON FiringPlayer.PlayerID = FireEvent.PlayerID
          AND FiringPlayer.ExerciseID = FireEvent.ExcerciseID
    LEFT JOIN Player HitPlayer
           ON HitPlayer.PlayerID = HitEvent.PlayerID
          AND HitPlayer.ExerciseID = FireEvent.ExcerciseID
   where FireEvent.ExerciseID = 'D289D508-1479-4C17-988C-5F6A847AE51E'
  ) as temp
  where HitRank=1 or HitEventID is null
)
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  I do have one question though before I mark your answer as correct.  How can I use this as part of an insert statement?

Comment: Infact, scratch that.  I'm only getting 20% of the records I get using the same filtering criteria but using cursors... hmmm...

Comment: Also, I still need all of the FireEvents (the ones that don't pair need to be included too).

Comment: OK, I've made all the changes I need, except that I still cant get it to work with an inert statement... @dbenham Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Hmm, that is very odd. The outer join in the CTE should preserve unmatched FireEvents. HitEventID=NULL should be a valid partition group for the RANK function as well. It seems to me the query should work. In answer to your 1st question (assuming the query works), you simply do `with RankedHits as (...) insert into tableName (columnList) select (columns) from RankedHits where HitRank=1`.

Comment: @vijay - OK, I just read your last comment. Did you find and fix a bug in my query, or did you just need to fix things on your end?

Comment: I've changed your query slightly: http://pastebin.com/g1MY5FrS

But I appear to have broken it (or it didn't really work :S)  I am getting duplicate HitEvent rows returned...

Let me know what I need to change, this is the full query which is fairly large....

Comment: @vijay - I see where my original query was wrong - the HitResult constraint needed to be moved within the outer join clause. I also posted a fix to your insert statement.

Comment: Where is the change?  Pastebin doesn't link me automatically to your update.  If you somehow updated the post itself, then the same issue of the same HitEvent appearing multiple times is still there...

Comment: @vijay - I updated the answer above with the fixed insert statement. I did not post to Pastebin.

Comment: Your updated code in your post has the issue of the exact same HitEvent appearing multiple times... One player has "fired" multiple times in a short period of time, so there are three FireEvents which potentially match with one hit event, they all appear to be pairing, they shouldn't.  Only the best match (closest) should match...

Comment: The only thing I can think of is maybe your joins to the player table are returning too many rows. It may work if you substitute row_number() for rank(), but then the answer will not be determinate. Better to fix the joins or alter the order by clause so that only one row per hit event is ranked as 1.

Comment: I was able to fix the duplicates by changing the partition to "partition by HitEvent.EventTime, HitEvent.HitEventID" <- it looks like it's fixed now... but not 100%...

The player table joins return 0/1, so they're not the issue.
Rank seems to be the right things to use here.
I think the main issue is that when a HitEvent ranks the FireEvents within it's 10 second time window those FireEvents which ranked cannot be matched to another HitEvent, only the FireEvent ranked 1 should be ignored... Is that something you can help with?

Comment: @Vijay - I don't see how addding HitEvent.EventTime to the partition clause can help. I hope HitEventID and FireEventID are PKs, so a given event can only have one EventTime. Even if that were not true, extending the partition clause could create more duplicates, not fewer. And your last statement is just not true. The query allows the same FireEvent to be paired with any number of HitEvents. I finally tracked down the missing unmatched FireEvents and updated both statements. The critical change is the last WHERE clause in both statements. I don't think I have any more advice to give.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is wat u want  but u can use CTE at the beginning of the query

```
  With cte as (
  SELECT FireEvent.ExerciseID, 
   FireEvent.FireEventID, 
   tempHitEvent.HitEventID, 
   FireEvent.AssociatedPlayerID, 
   tempHitEvent.AssociatedPlayerID, 
   FireEvent.EventTime, 
   tempHitEvent.EventTime, 
   FireEvent.Longitude, 
   FireEvent.Latitude, 
   tempHitEvent.Longitude, 
   tempHitEvent.Latitude, 
   tempHitEvent.HitResult, 
   FireEvent.AmmunitionCode, 
   FireEvent.AmmunitionSource, 
   FireEvent.FireEventID, 
   0 AS 'IsArtillery' 
 FROM   FireEvent )
 Select * from CTE 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT HitEvent.*, 
                     FireEvent.FireEventID, 
                     Rank() 
                       OVER ( 
                         ORDER BY HitEvent.EventTime) AS RankValue 
              FROM   HitEvent 
                     INNER JOIN FireEvent 
                             ON FireEvent.EventTime BETWEEN 
                                Dateadd(millisecond, -5000, 
                                HitEvent.EventTime) AND 
                                           Dateadd(millisecond, 
                                           5000, HitEvent.EventTime) AND      HitEvent.FiringPlayerID = FireEvent.PlayerID 
               AND HitEvent.AmmunitionCode = 
                   FireEvent.AmmunitionCode
               AND HitEvent.ExerciseID = 
                   'D289D508-1479-4C17-988C-5F6A847AE51E' 
                    AND FireEvent.ExerciseID = 
                   'D289D508-1479-4C17-988C-5F6A847AE51E' 
               AND HitEvent.HitResult NOT IN ( 0, 1 ) ) AS 
             tempHitEvent 
          ON ( 
          RankValue = 1
        AND tempHitEvent.FireEventID = 
                 FireEvent.FireEventID 
                 )
  WHERE  FireEvent.ExerciseID = 'D289D508-1479-4C17-988C-5F6A847AE51E' 
  ORDER BY HitEventID
```

Comment: This doesn't work... I have like 20 errors when I paste it into SQL.  I don't think you quite grasped the table structures from the look of how you modified the query... But I probably haven't explained them well enough!

Answer (score 0):

The following wildly simplified example should produce optimal pairs.  Considering the current hour, it might produce gerbils and I wouldn't notice.

```
declare @Fires as Table ( FireId Int Identity, FireTime Int )
insert into @Fires ( FireTime ) values
  ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 5 ), ( 8 ), ( 13 ), ( 21 ), ( 34 )

declare @Hits as Table ( HitId Int Identity, HitTime Int )
insert into @Hits ( HitTime ) values
  ( 5 ), ( 7 ), ( 12 ), ( 12 ), ( 20 ), ( 21 ), ( 30 )

-- Create a temporary table of all possible pairs meeting the time criteria.
select F.*, Dense_Rank() over ( partition by H.HitTime, H.HitId order by F.FireTime, F.FireId ) as [FireRank],
  H.*, Dense_Rank() over ( order by H.HitTime, H.HitId ) as [HitRank]
  into #Pairs
  from @Fires as F inner join
    @Hits as H on F.FireTime between H.HitTime - 5 and H.HitTime + 5

-- Clean up the pairs.
declare @HitRank as Int = 1
declare @MaxHitRank as Int = ( select Max( HitRank ) from #Pairs )
declare @MinFireRank as Int
while ( @HitRank <= @MaxHitRank )
  begin
  select @MinFireRank = Min( FireRank ) from #Pairs where HitRank = @HitRank
  delete from #Pairs
    where
      -- It is not the first   FireRank   for the current   HitRank .
      ( HitRank = @HitRank and FireRank > @MinFireRank ) or
      -- Once we pair a fire event don't pair it against another hit event.
      ( HitRank > @HitRank and FireId in ( select FireId from #Pairs where HitRank = @HitRank and FireRank = @MinFireRank ) )
  set @HitRank = @HitRank + 1
  end

-- Select the paired events.
select FireId, FireTime, HitId, HitTime
  from #Pairs
union
-- Add in the unpaired fire events.
select FireId, FireTime, NULL, NULL
  from @Fires
  where FireId not in ( select FireId from #Pairs )
order by FireTime, FireId, HitTime, HitId

drop table #Pairs
```

Comment: Because of the "in" statements this is painfully inefficient... I ran it for 10 minutes and it only manages to get through 30 records...  Thanks for the attempt though, but my previous cursor version was faster... :P